# Restrict access in Laravel Nova

Tags: laravel, laravel-nova

i'm using nova in a project and i want to give acces to dashboard to admin user only. So i try this according to the doc, but i don't know why it's not working. Anyone can hep me to achieve this ! thank's

**method gate of NovaServiceProvider here:**

```
 protected function gate()
{
    Gate::define('viewNova', function ($user) {
        $this->isAdmin($user);
    });
}

**here i checked if admin user** 

public function isAdmin(User $user)
{
    return $user->type == 3 ? true : false;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe it is because you forgot to return it.

```
protected function gate()
{
    Gate::define('viewNova', function ($user) {
        return $this->isAdmin($user); // You need to return
    });
}
```

Comment: Thank you  @Saumini Navaratnam i'll try it and tell you

Comment: It's works  @Saumini Navaratnam thank you for your help .

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you that add a column on your database table for permission.
For example, your permissions is: admin & user

so insert below on your migration:
$table->enum('permission', ['admin', 'user'])->default('user');

(sorry because of my awful english)
see it:
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/migrations#column-method-enum